# Can passing a non string literal the c function strftime create a uncontrolled format string vulnerability

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, string-literals, strftime

I am using the strftime function for a project and I pass to it a user supplied string instead of a string literal. Being overly cautious I compile by passing gcc every warning flag and because I am not passing a string literal to strftime I am getting a warning telling me I am using a non string literal.

I am assuming this is to prevent an uncontrolled format string vulnerability that the printf() function is vulnerable to. However investigating a bit I read that the vulnerability stems from printf() being a variadic function. However strftime() is not a variadic function.

Does passing a user supplied string open my program up to a vulnerability or is gcc warning overly cautious?

Comment: There’s a limit to the damage that’s possible. The string buffer is bounded by the size you give. There are no “write” format specifier (whereas `printf()` has `%n`).  About the worst that can happen is that you get gibberish. I18N requires variable formats.

Comment: I'd say it's a grey area.  I've written programs that passed user-supplied format strings directly to `strftime`.  I agree with Jonathan Leffler that the potential for damage is limited.  I'm tempted to say that the warning is overly cautious, but in general such warnings are a good idea, in an attempt to combat the laxness of the past.

Comment: The `%z` and `%Z` specifiers in `strftime` are weakly defined.  It's conceivable that under some implementation, an unexpected implementation of `%Z` in combination with an unexpectedly-defined local time zone could lead to some kind of mischief.  So if someone wants to be paranoid, wants to pronounce programs as guilty until proven innocent of having security vulnerabilities, this warning for `strftime` is probably appropriate.  Even though it *seems* pretty likely that `strftime` is "safe", the ironclad proof might be too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to *constrain user input*. That is, do not let them specify the format string. Instead, give them a set of choices that they may select from as part of their user preferences.

If you wish, hard-code the choices into a constant array. This will stop the compiler from complaining. (It will also prevent savvy users from getting around your protections by manually adding a bad value to the possible choices in the configuration file.)

Comment: My goal is to allow my user to format a date string however they wanted following the rules of strftime().

I've mare my own stat program following the GNU stat format string rules which are similar to strftime() and printf(). By parsing the string manually and sending the individual bits to printf() or puts() as needed. To constrain user input for strftime() would I need to do something similar and parse the format string and pass the values to strftime() token by token ?

Comment: @ZenoofElea Yes, that would work. Either make the user select the individual components and order them as desired or filter the user's input to only accept specific formatting tokens.